# Why my bone moves with the whole mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

When I move a single bone in pose mode, the whole mesh is moving, not only the eye-lid, as I wish. What am I doing wrong? I set the parent: mesh to bone (armature deform, with autom. weights). How should I precise, I want only the specific eyelid to move with that specific bone and not the whole mesh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reassign the influence of your eyelid bone to the eyelid vertices of your mesh.

As L0Lock said, you can fix your problem in *Weight Paint* mode, with the *Mix* or *Substract* brush.

You can also do it with the *Vertex Groups* "Assign" button:

- Select your object, go in *Edit* mode, go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Vertex Groups*.
- In the vertex groups list, select the vertex group that has the name of your eyelid bone.
- On the right of the vertex groups list, there's a down arrow that gives access to a menu. Press *Remove from All Groups*. Now there's no more vertices in this group, so the eyelid bone can't move anymore vertex.
- In your mesh, select the vertices that are supposed to be part of the eyelid vertex group.
- In the vertex groups, keep the eyelid vertex group select, and click on the *Assign* button that is under the list. You can modulate the assign ratio to give more or less influence to the brush.

Comment: This is a correct way of assigning weights but is very limited. Basically, as soon as you need nice ease between areas (basically any organic mesh), you should use the weight paint mode. It's a nice way to have a strong basis to work on with weight paint mode though.

Comment: yes, he could also use the weight paint mode, but if you do it with the Vertex Groups you can also modulate the Assign ratio

Comment: of course you can, but it's way more harsh to assign manually weights ratios on vertices than giving a few brush strokes. Also, weight paint gives more visual feedback on what's going on, and offers some tools, like normalization, global smoothing, ...

Comment: ok, I've edited my answer so that he can choose